# My script won't work as expected, it also crashes the unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on this project for some days now and I've encountered a bug that seems impossible to solve because not only *no error messages* appear but it also 'skips' my debug messages and crashes the editor itself.

The following script is a dialog displayer, it's apparently what's causing the issue (forgive the messed code, i messed it around while trying to solve the problem):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class DialogDisplayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Dialog[] dialogFiles;
    TextMeshPro outputTxt;

    bool next, finished;
    char comma = (char)44;
    char period = (char)46;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        outputTxt = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
        StartCoroutine(type());
    }

    IEnumerator type()
    {
        int dialogIndex = 0;

        do
        {
            foreach (char c in dialogFiles[dialogIndex].dialogText)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
                {
                    outputTxt.text = dialogFiles[dialogIndex].dialogText;
                    Debug.Log("z pressed in the foreach");
                    break;
                }

                outputTxt.text += c;
                if (c == ' ')
                    continue;

                if (dialogFiles[dialogIndex].delayforPunctuations)
                {
                    if (c == comma)
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dialogFiles[dialogIndex].delayBetweenLetters + 0.1f);
                    else if (c == period)
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dialogFiles[dialogIndex].delayBetweenLetters + 0.2f);
                    else
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dialogFiles[dialogIndex].delayBetweenLetters);
                }
                else
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dialogFiles[dialogIndex].delayBetweenLetters);
            }
            Debug.Log("Either finished or broken out of the loop");

            while (!finished)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Entering while loop");
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
                {
                    Debug.Log("entered if");
                    finished = true;
                    dialogIndex++;
                }
                Debug.Log("got out");
            }

        } while (dialogIndex != dialogFiles.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Unity expert but I don't think you want to call `type()` (great name for a method btw) when you start the coroutine. I think you pass it the method info: `StartCoroutine(type);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use `yield return` anywhere in your [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html). This will [cause your coroutine to run all iterations in the same frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41720468/1299146).

From the [Scripting documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html):

```
// every 2 seconds perform the print()
private IEnumerator WaitAndPrint(float waitTime)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        print("WaitAndPrint " + Time.time);
    }
}
```

Or you can use `yield return null` to pass the coroutine onto the next frame:

```
private IEnumerator YourDialogCoroutine()
{
    bool finished = false;

    while (!finished)
    {
        If(Input.GetKeyDown("Z"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Ending loop!");
            finished = true;
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get that. Could you be more specific?

Comment: In the documentation for Coroutines, you have to use the statement `yield return` and either `null` or something like `WaitForSeconds(float seconds)`. I would review the documentation in this case since you are missing this statement

Comment: Actually there are several `yield return`s...

Comment: Coroutines will process all the information within a single frame (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32469037/1299146). Once your code falls through your foreach loop, there is no `yield return null` at the end of your do-while.

Comment: so, i'd have to add a yield return null at the end of the do while?

Comment: I highly doubt that the use of a foreach and while inside of a do-while inside of a coroutine is not the issue either. I would comment out sections of your coroutine to find where the crash is happening. Start with commenting out the coroutine call itself, then blocks of your coroutine.

Comment: I did it already, i i figured out that the while(!finished) line is whats causing the problem.. i'm now trying to find an alternative...

Comment: If you put a `yield return null` at the end of your `while(!finished)` loop, it will move onto the next frames while it waits for your input. Otherwise, it'll keep grinding away at that while loop inside of a single frame.

Comment: ok, I'l try that

Comment: @Eliasar Thank you a lot. It's working now

Comment: @EvertonColombo If this solution provided your answer, would you mind marking it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see....

In English:  As soon as dialogIndex is not equal to dialogFiles.length minus one your script crashes.

Once this:

```
while (dialogIndex != dialogFiles.Length - 1);
```

is true, it enters into a endless loop.  There are no directions of what to do once dialogFiles.Length -1 no longer is equal to dialogIndex.

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the final line of code there, but neither is the computer and it just waits for instructions once those conditions are met....forever.

It needs to be

```
while (dialogIndex != dialogFiles.Length - 1); {
  Do Something;
  provide Action To Eventually escape this loop (make dialogIndex = dialogFiles.Length - 1)
}
```

As for as the comment goes, you can do `StartCoroutine(type());` or `StartCoroutine("type");`  That's fine.

Comment: that last line of code (while(dialogIndex != dialogFiles.Lenght - 1)) is actually part of a do while loop. And, while waiting for an answer, i've also found out that the line of code causing the problem is actually the while(!finished) loop, I still don't know why though.

Comment: just to make it clear, the goal of this script is to type out dialogFiles[dialogIndex].dialogText whit a type writer effect while also having the possibility to speed up the typing process by pressing 'z' on the keyboard and, once all the text was typed out, pressing 'z' again would lead to increasing dialogIndex by one.