# Coroutine yield return null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, coroutine

This is my first question..

I learning how to make games using C# and Unity so I came across **Coroutines** and I know how these methods work but there is one thing that I didn't understand which is:

```
yield return null
```

For example:

```
IEnumerator Attack(){
   // Somecode..
   while(true){
   //DoSomething..
   yield return null
}
}
```

This question has been asked here: [Unity - IEnumerator's yield return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720221/unity-ienumerators-yield-return-null)

But I still need more explanation

Please excuse me if this question is a stupid one but like I said i'm just learning.

Thank you.

Comment: "more explanation" is rather vague, what in particular is it that you're not understanding? `yield return null` will apparently (if I'm reading that answer right) make the coroutine continue on the next frame.

Comment: Sorry about that, Thats the point "continue on the next frame!" what does that even mean?@LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: Continue when MoveNext is called on the enumerator from IEnumerable.GetEnumerator

Comment: You could think of coroutines just like updates with extra control. A started coroutines gets added to a list for tge given MonoBehaviour, when the conpiler runs them, if it hits a yield return null, it stops with the coroutine and sets it back in the list. The current frame is run through and next frame starts. At some point compiler processes the coroutine list and runs the coroutine again until the end of the method or reaching another yield. In first case, coroutine object is disposed, second case, it is set back in the list and on the go again.

Answer (score 1):

Every game is loop based. You can see this logic in simplified picture:

[image]

[Here's full Unity frame logic chart](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/monobehaviour_flowchart.svg) thanks to @Draco18s.

One iteration of this loop is called a "frame". `yield return null` work like a `continue` keyword in loops - it just proceeds to next game loop iteration aka "frame".

For a better understanding let's create a coroutine which prints current frame number each frame:

```
void Awake () {
    StartCoroutine(PrintFrameCount());
}

IEnumerator PrintFrameCount() {
    for (;;) {           
        Debug.Log(Time.frameCount);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Such coroutine prints only distinct values of current frame count which can be changed only by printing it in different frames.

[image]

Comment: Minor side note for future readers: `yield`ing on different values can be important in some cases, as they will get "picked up" and continued at different points in the cycle. For example, `yield null` is *almost* at the top, just after all `Update()` calls, while `yield WaitForEndOfFrame` is all the way at the bottom. This is useful if you need to wait for other things to complete and you know they'll complete "this frame" but haven't been processed yet and you don't want to wait all the way until the *next* frame. However, for most part, these distinctions aren't that important.