# (Beginner) Coroutine crashing unity. Not sure why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not sure what's going on but one of my coroutines is completely crashing unity. This is the coroutine in question.

```
IEnumerator attack() 
{
    currentState = state.attack;
    pathFinder.enabled = false;

    Vector3 origin = transform.position;
    Vector3 attackPos = target.position;
    float percent = 0;
    float attackSpeed = 3;

    while(percent <= 1) 
    {
        percent += Time.deltaTime * attackSpeed;
        float interpolation = (-Mathf.Pow(percent, 2) + percent) * 4;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(origin, attackPos, interpolation);

        yield return null;
    }
    currentState = state.chase;
    pathFinder.enabled = true;
}
```

A lot of code here might seem bad. I'm following a tutorial, probably heard that one a lot here, and on their end, it seems to be working fine but right when I press play it freezes unity forcing me to close it. Here's the entire script if that would give a better understanding of what could be going on

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
 
[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class Enemy : LivingEntity 
{
    public enum state { idle, chase, attack};
 
    private state currentState;
    private NavMeshAgent pathFinder;
    private Transform target;
    private float attackThreshhold = .5f;
    private float timeBetweenAttacks = 1;
    private float attackTimer;
    private float myCollisionRadius;
    private float targetCollisionRadius;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    protected override void Start() 
    {
        base.Start();
        currentState = state.chase;
        pathFinder = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        myCollisionRadius = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().radius;
        targetCollisionRadius = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().radius;
 
        StartCoroutine(updatePath());
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
        if(Time.time > attackTimer)
        {
            float sqrDistanceToTarget = (target.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
            if (sqrDistanceToTarget < Mathf.Pow(attackThreshhold + myCollisionRadius + targetCollisionRadius, 2)) {
                attackTimer = Time.time + timeBetweenAttacks;
                StartCoroutine(attack());
            }
        }
    }
 
    IEnumerator attack() 
    {
        currentState = state.attack;
        pathFinder.enabled = false;
 
        Vector3 origin = transform.position;
        Vector3 attackPos = target.position;
        float percent = 0;
        float attackSpeed = 3;
 
        while(percent <= 1) 
        {
            percent += Time.deltaTime * attackSpeed;
            float interpolation = (-Mathf.Pow(percent, 2) + percent) * 4;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(origin, attackPos, interpolation);
 
            yield return null;
        }

        currentState = state.chase;
        pathFinder.enabled = true;
    }
 
    IEnumerator updatePath() 
    {
        float refreshRate = .25f;
        
        while(target != null) 
        {
            if(currentState == state.chase) 
            {
                Vector3 dirToTarget = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
                Vector3 targetPosition = target.position - dirToTarget * (myCollisionRadius + targetCollisionRadius/2);
                if (!dead) pathFinder.SetDestination(targetPosition);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(refreshRate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the other routine in `updatePath`.

> ```
> while(target != null) 
> {
>     if(currentState == state.chase) 
>     {
>         Vector3 dirToTarget = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
>         Vector3 targetPosition = target.position - dirToTarget * (myCollisionRadius + targetCollisionRadius/2);
>         if (!dead) pathFinder.SetDestination(targetPosition);
>         yield return new WaitForSeconds(refreshRate);
>     }
> }
> ```

**Problem:** In the case your are **not** in the state `state.chase` you never `yield` => you have an infinite `while` loop!

---

It should probably rather be

```
while(target != null) 
{
    if(currentState == state.chase) 
    {
        var dirToTarget = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        var targetPosition = target.position - dirToTarget * (myCollisionRadius + targetCollisionRadius / 2);
        if (!dead) pathFinder.SetDestination(targetPosition);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(refreshRate);
    }
    // In other cases wait one frame
    else
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you this solved my issue! And thank you for letting me know what caused the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Because at some point percent goes negative. It also never goes above 1. I would say your math is incorrect. Try removing the negative infront of `Mathf.Pow`

Comment: @user151119845 Tried to do what you said and it still crashes unity.

Comment: How math function can broke it. Math function isn't related to **percent** value in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Math function has nothing to do with crash. Unity crashes because, @SOPMOD is running while loop infinetly. That causing a overflow. Your code tells it should break while loop when percent value is smaller or equal to 1 but you are yielding it null everytime inside the while loop. **yield return null** tells to compiler, coroutine will run in next frame. So, coroutine start again and percent value is set to 0 again. While loop run again and coroutine again will yield null. Infinite coroutine loop is crashing your app. Move

```
float percent = 0;
```

decleration to outside of function. Move it to class level and you will be fine. Because if it is in the class level, it will hold previous value and it will able to **reach >1**.

Here is [How Coroutine yields work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720221/unity-ienumerators-yield-return-null)

Comment: yiled will not restart the coroutine, it will stay inside the while loop

Comment: @A.Gerber Oh my bad, you are right. But still solution is same. Moving **percent** variable to class level will solve it.

Comment: I agree with the overflow but letting percent here is okay I think. Shouldn't be better to use Mathf.Clamp to avoid this overflow?

Comment: @A.Gerber where OP is using **Mathf.Clamp**? I don't see anything like that in code.

Comment: Yes that's why maybe he should use it to avoid the overflow. But I wanted your point of view on that

Comment: People, this has nothing to do with the `percent` value .. everyone is jumping on that train but that routine is perfectly fine (yes there could be concurrent routines braking the movement of the object, but each of these routines will terminate after about 1/3 seconds. It's the other way round: If you make `percent` a class field then it is shared along all routines and might get stuck forever. Still as long as you yield it won't freeze Unity completely. the issue is the other routine that doesn't yield at all in some cases ;)